# Adding a fade in/fade out effect to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a function that loads in a JSON file and changes the contents of several divs on my page.  This part works correct, but I wanted to make it look sexy. When the button that calls this function is clicked, the new text immediately replaces the old text. I wanted the old text to fade out, change the text, and fade in the new text.

Here is my code

```
function loadNextPassage()
    {
    //Fading out effect
    $("#passage-title").fadeOut();
    $("#title").fadeOut();
    $("#pre-post").fadeOut();
    $("#passage").fadeOut();
    $("#media").fadeOut();

    //load the new JSON file and change the elements
    $.getJSON("passage-2.3.2.JSON", function( data ) {

    document.getElementById("passage-title").innerHTML = data["passageNumber"];
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data["title"];
    document.getElementById("pre-post").innerHTML = data["preReading"];
    document.getElementById("pre-reading-content").innerHTML = data["preReading"];
    document.getElementById("post-reading-content").innerHTML = data["postReading"];
    document.getElementById("passage").innerHTML = data["reading"];
    document.getElementById("media").innerHTML = data["media"];

    //fading the elements back in
    $("#passage-title").fadeIn();
    $("#title").fadeIn();
    $("#pre-post").fadeIn();
    $("#passage").fadeIn();
    $("#media").fadeIn();
});
}
```

I am running into a problem when I push my button to call this function, the code changes the elements and then fades out and back in.  I was hoping I could fade out the text then change the elements and then finally fade it back in.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The main problems:

1. Don't mix **Pure DOM** and **jQuery**. Use the right tool for what you're doing, regardless of the tools you have available
2. First `fadeOut()` and in the callback, change the text and `fadeIn()`.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    $("p").fadeOut(400, function () {
      $(this).html("Second One").fadeIn(400);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Next</button>
<p>First One</p>
```

Comment: My point was that sometimes, the pure DOM option **is** the right tool, even if you're using jQuery. Classic example: `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id")`; there's just no reason to use jQuery there. So mixing DOM and jQuery is fine -- just now how the OP was doing it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` has a `complete` callback so when `fadeOut` ends is called:

```
function loadNextPassage() {
    var timeout = 400;
    //Fading out effect
    $("#passage-title").fadeOut(timeout);
    $("#title").fadeOut(timeout);
    $("#pre-post").fadeOut(timeout);
    $("#passage").fadeOut(timeout);
    $("#media").fadeOut(timeout, function() {
        //load the new JSON file and change the elements
        $.getJSON("passage-2.3.2.JSON", function( data ) {
            document.getElementById("passage-title").innerHTML = data["passageNumber"];
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data["title"];
            document.getElementById("pre-post").innerHTML = data["preReading"];
            document.getElementById("pre-reading-content").innerHTML = data["preReading"];
            document.getElementById("post-reading-content").innerHTML = data["postReading"];
            document.getElementById("passage").innerHTML = data["reading"];
            document.getElementById("media").innerHTML = data["media"];

            //fading the elements back in
            $("#passage-title").fadeIn(timeout);
            $("#title").fadeIn(timeout);
            $("#pre-post").fadeIn(timeout);
            $("#passage").fadeIn(timeout);
            $("#media").fadeIn(timeout);
        });
    });
}
```

Talking about other things, a better optimization for this will be to have all your elements inside one element (a `div`, for example) and only `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` that element.

Also, if you want to have an instant `fadeIn` just after `fadeOut` ends instead of waiting for your `JSON` to load, you can start loading you `JSON` at the same time that you `fadeOut`, flag both `complete` callbacks and `fadeIn` when both callbacks have been called, so while your button is fading out your JSON is being loaded, earning precious 400 milliseconds.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/